# bash- IF with multiple condition using IN

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have the following script to check for multiple condition occurred.

**Script**:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "1.Add,  2.Sub, 3.Mul, 4.Div"
echo "Enter your choice:"
read ch

#Here i want to check the condition for 1, 01 and also 001
if [ $ch = 1 ]
then
     echo "Addition goes here"
...
...
fi
```

**Note**: How can i use multiple condition using `IN`?

Like:

```
if  [ $ch IN ('1','01','001') ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `case` statement instead:

```
case $ch in
  1|01|001)
    echo "Addition goes here"
    ;;
  ...
  *)
    echo "Invalid input"
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

With bash, you can write:

```
if [[ $ch == @(1|01|001) ]]
```

Inside `[[ ... ]]`, the `==` operator does *pattern matching*, and the extended pattern `@(pattern-list)` matches one or more of  the given pattern.

docs:
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching